# use a QList<QVariantMap> as a model for a QML ListView

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I can't figure out how to use a QList as a model. There are several examples where the data type is one dimensional but haven't seen something nested like this.
Relevant code below:

main.cpp - here i register the QList

```
viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("productlist", QVariant::fromValue(databaseController.listProjects()) );
```

main.qml - here i want to use the model 'productlist'

```
ListView {
    id: list_view

    anchors.fill: parent
    model: productlist
    delegate:
        Rectangle{
           height: 20
           width: 200
           color: "#CCCCCC"
           Text { text:  modelData.name }
        }
}
```

Note, if I use **databaseController.listProjects()[0]** I can get the first QVariantMap of course and the example works, though I am not sure how to iterate over the values and/or keys.

I'm using QtQuick 2.0 and Qt 5

I have read something about QAbstractListModel but can't figure out how to use it.. am I on the right track there or is there an easier way?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can easily use a QVariantList as a model for a ListView, though you need to know that it's going to be read-only, as the value() of QVariantList/QVariantMap is const :

```
QVariantList myModel;
foreach (QVariantMap item, databaseController.listProjects()) {
    myModel.append (item);
}

viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("productlist", QVariant::fromValue(myModel));
```

And it's done !

Comment: How is a QVariantlist equivalent to a QList<QVariantMap> ? (genuine question, I have the same problem as OP)

Comment: @FélixCantournet: in fact QVariantList is a typedef for QList<QVariant>, and QVariant can be transparently filled with a QVariantMap, so one can feed QVariantMap as item for a QVariantList.